# Contains the word but not a specific word before it

Tags: java, c#, regex

I need help in regular expressions. The code is in SQL and I would like to match the all string that is not referencing proxy database.

The pattern would be:
Contains `..` and the word before it is not equal to `proxy`

I would like to match the example word `customer` below:

```
from proxy..vw_xxx a join customer..vw_xxx b
from proxy..vw_xxx
insert into proxy..vw_xxx
from customer..vw_xxx
```

**Edit:**
How about if I would also like to capture the DDL statement.
For Example:

`CREATE VIEW vw_yyy
AS
...
from proxy..vw_xxx a join customer..vw_xxx b
from proxy..vw_xxx
insert into proxy..vw_xxx
from customer..vw_xxx
GO
CREATE VIEW vw_zzz
AS
SELECT * FROM customer.vw_xxx
GO`

I would just like to capture the first CREATE VIEW.
I used the regex:

> CREATE VIEW.*\w+(?<!proxy)...*GO

and
/gmis option
but it's also matching the second creation of view.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind based regex.

java regex

```
"\\w+(?<!proxy)\\.\\."
```

C# regex

```
@"\w+(?<!proxy)\.\."
```

`\w+` matches one or more word characters and following double dots only if the dots are not preceded by the word `proxy`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uM8uX2/1)

```
String s = "from proxy..vw_xxx a join customer..vw_xxx b\n" + 
        "from proxy..vw_xxx\n" + 
        "insert into proxy..vw_xxx\n" + 
        "from customer..vw_xxx";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\w+(?<!proxy)\\.\\.").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
customer..
customer..
```

Comment: add word boundary if necessary `\w+(?<!\bproxy)\.\.`

Comment: Hi, I had a followup above. I'm not sure if it's really possible. Would appreciate your inputs. Thanks again.

Comment: if you have any further queries, please ask it as a new question. With an explanation of `I'm not sure if it's really possible.` how?