# Visual Studio Search: finding a word, but not when preceded by a specific word

Tags: regex, visual-studio

For example, I am trying to find all instances of "dog", but not the "dog" in "hot dog" in a text file with Visual Studio's text search. [I found a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271443/contains-the-word-but-not-a-specific-word-before-it) and tried its accepted answer.

```
\w+(?<!hot) dog
```

It does exclude "hot dog", but the problem is that it matches for all possible combinations for other cases. That is, for "hunting dog", I have to click "Find next" 7 times to move to the next instance, because VS stops for all of the following portions of that one instance.

```
hunting dog
unting dog
nting dog
ting dog
ing dog
ng dog
g dog
```

Also, it does not match the word, if it is not preceded by anything (the first word). How can I change the expression?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not entirely clear.
If you want to find the word "dog", then in the search you need to specify only it.
If you want to find the previous word + dog then use

```
\b\w+\s+dog
```

To exclude the word "hot"

```
(?<!hot )\bdog
```

Comment: I want to find all instances of "dog", except the instances of "dog" which is preceded by "hot".

Comment: `(?<!hot )\bdog` worked as I expected, when I tested it with "dog cat hot dog mouse hunting dog bird cow dog". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try pattern `(?!<hot )dog`

Pattern explanation:

`(?!<hot )` - negative lookbehind - assert what preceeds is not `hot`

`dog` - match `dog` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fXeo1e/1)

Comment: When I tested it with "dog cat hot dog mouse hunting dog bird cow dog", that expression matched with all instances of "dog". It should not match with the second "dog".